# Breaking out of JavaScript 'For' Loop using False?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, break, boolean-expression

I didn't know this was possible (is it?)

The below code apparently logs values 1 to 5, then breaks out of the 'for' loop, because the 'false' value is returned.

```
function x() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 5) return false;
    }
    return true
}

console.log(x());
```

My question is:

- How come the for loop short-circuits when 'false' is returned? I looked at MDN but there is nothing there about using 'false' to break out of the for loop. Also tried looking at ECMA specs, but sadly too noob.
- Why doesn't the function return 'true' to the console, as the 'return true' statement exists after the 'for' loop is executed? Even if false somehow returns 'first', shouldn't 'true' return last or also?

Comment: The `return` statement will force to return the control from the current function to which called the current function... so in this case it will come out of the loop and return `false` to the caller

Comment: If i could give reputation or points or whatever it's called to everyone who answered, I so would. That's cleared everything up for me, thank you guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`return false` is not breaking your loop but returning control outside back.

```
function x() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 5) return false;
    }
    return true
}

console.log(x())
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
false //here returning false and control also
```

Where `break` will break your loop instead of coming out from function.

```
function x() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 5) break;
    }
    return true
}

console.log(x())
```

Will output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5 //after this loop is breaking and ouputing true
true
```

Answer (score 2):

The return statement ends the function , so the return true line is unreachable. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> The below code apparently logs values 1 to 5, then breaks out of the
>   'for' loop, because the 'false' value is returned.

Wrong, it breaks out of the `for` loop because of the `return`, not because of the `false`. You could write `return x` with the same effect. Point is, `return` immediatly drops out of the enclosing `function`, whatever loop or conditional is being executed currently.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will never be executed till 10. `return false` will return control to caller of the function x as soon as i is equal to 5. The `return true` line is unreachable.
This is your code

```
function x() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i == 5) return false;
    }
    return true
}

console.log(x());
```

Output:-

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 false
```

If you want it reach to the return true statement you may want to do something like adding a `break` instead of `return false` in `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            if (i == 5) break;//this will put it outside for loop
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want mess with return or break statements, you can add just one boolean flag. In my example i use isFound flag to run loop until your requirements are meet or end of array.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

for(let i = 0, isFound; !isFound; i++){
  if(i >= 3 || i >= arr.length){isFound = true;}
  else { console.log(arr[i]);}
}
```

So the output will be:

```
1
2 
3
```